# Regex for specific url format

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I am trying to get a regex expression to match a specific url format. Specifically the api urls for stackexchange. For example I want both of these to match:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/1234/answers  
http://api.physics.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/5678/answers
```

Where

- everything not in bold must identical.
- The first bold part, can only be made of a to z, and either one or no full stop.

  - Also it would be good, if there is one full stop the word "stackexchange" must follow. However this isn't crucial.
- The second bold part can only be a 1 or a 0.
- The last bold part can be only numbers 0 to 9, and can be any length
- There can't be anything at all before or after the url, not even a trailing slash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("^(?i:http://api\\.(?:[a-z]+(?:\\.stackexchange)?)\\.com)/1\\.[01]/questions/[0-9]+/answers\\z")
```

The `^` makes sure it starts at the start of input, and the `\\z` makes sure it ends at the end of input.  All the dots are escaped so they are literal.  The `(?i:...)` part makes the domain and scheme case-insensitive as per the URL spec.  The `[01]` only matches the characters 0 or 1.  The `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more Arabic digits.  The rest is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

```
^http://api[.][a-z]+([.]stackexchange)?[.]com/1[.][01]/questions/[0-9]+/answers$
```

`^` matches start-of-string, `$` matches end-of-line, `[.]` is an alternative way to escape the dot than a backslash (which itself would need to be escaped as `\\.`).

Comment: `$` in Java regex does not guarantee a match at the end.  From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html .  For example, `Pattern.compile("foo$")` will match `"foo\n"`.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference in the OP's case, multiline URLs are a freaky thing to see.

Comment: you're right.  Line separators are not allowed unescaped in URLs, but the OP does not make it clear whether the string has a priori been validated as a URL.

Comment: The reason it needs to be strict is because it also being used as a tag to identify another object. Some objects will have the same tag, and they need to be indentical else they wont group correctly, in other words of I need to get all objects with a specific URL and some objects have a break line on the end or a trailing slash for some reason they won't be included.

Answer (score 0):

This tested Java program has a commented regex which should do the trick:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/1234/answers";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "http://api\\.              # Scheme and api subdomain.\n" +
            "(?:                        # Group for domain alternatives.\n" +
            "  stackoverflow            # Either one\n" +
            "| physics\\.stackexchange  # or the other\n" +
            ")                          # End group for domain alternatives.\n" +
            "\\.com                     # TLD\n" +
            "/1\\.[01]                  # Either 1.0 or 1.1\n" +
            "/questions/\\d+/answers    # Rest of path.", 
            Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.print("Match found.\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("No match found.\n");
        }
    }
}
```